# Usage of question mark in regular expression

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I am trying to parse an xml but before parsing it I am cleaning some unnecassary attributes from it by using Regex.Replace method of .NET.

**This is my input**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
 <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="urn:Magento" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
 <SOAP-ENV:Body>
 <ns1:loginResponse>
  <loginReturn xsi:type="xsd:string">asdsadsadasdas2321312dasdasdas21asdas</loginReturn> 
  </ns1:loginResponse>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
  </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

**This is what I wrote for regex**

```
xmlns:[a-zA-Z\d-=":\/\.]+
```

**This is output**

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
 <SOAP-ENV:Body>
 <ns1:loginResponse>
  <loginReturn xsi:type="xsd:string">asdsadsadasdas2321312dasdasdas21asdas</loginReturn> 
  </ns1:loginResponse>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
  </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

---

```
Found 5 matches:
xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:ns1="urn:Magento"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
String literals for use in programs:
C#
@"xmlns:[a-zA-Z\d-="":\/\.]+"
```

**and this is wanted output**

```
 <SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
 <SOAP-ENV:Body>
 <ns1:loginResponse>
  <loginReturn>asdsadsadasdas2321312dasdasdas21asdas</loginReturn> 
  </ns1:loginResponse>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
  </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

**I tried something like**

```
xmlns?xsi?[a-zA-Z\d-=":\/\.]+
```

but it doesnt work. It also doesnt seem that can solve the attributes that begins with SOAP-ENV anyway.

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you not using an XML parser for this?

Comment: Why can't you just use an XML parser?

Comment: I want my regex also mathes with SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle and xsi:type="xsd:string". They couldnt match with xmlns:[a-zA-Z\d-=":\/\.]+ Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this for a regex.. this might get you the output you want.

```
(xmlns:| SOAP-|xsi:)[\w-=":\/\.]+
```

The question mark makes the previous statement optional and in your case only makes the 's' and the 'i' optional

xmln **s**?xs **i**?[a-zA-Z\d-=":/.]+

If you meant to make the `xmln` and the `xsi` tags optional your regex should look like this

```
(xmlns)?(xsi)?[a-zA-Z\d-=":\/\.]+
```

This would catch alot since the regex will capture everthing in the `[a-zA-Z\d-=":\/\.]+` part as well

Answer (score 1):

Try to convert the string input to XmlElement and then use the XmlElement.RemoveAttribute method to remove the "encodingStyle" attribute.

Answer (score 0):

The question mark has special meaning in regex. Try escaping the question mark like so if you want to actually use them in your seach

```
 xmlns\?xsi\?[a-zA-Z\d-=":\/\.]+
```